# How to insert an embedded object with dot notations in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

For example, you can use dot notations while changing the contents of a object:

```py
collection.update_one({"_id": 123456}, {"$set": {"abc.def.ghi": 123}})
```

Which is great but, i cant use it to create new documents, when i do:

```py
collection.insert_one({"_id": 123456, "abc.def.ghi": 123})
```

To create a new document, it just inserts a document like this:

```json
{
    "_id": 123456,
    "abc.def.ghi": 123
}
```

While i want it to insert a document like this:

```json
{
    "_id": 123456,
    "abc": {
        "def": {
            "ghi": 123
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use dot notation in that way on an `insert_one()`. Just use:

```
collection.insert_one({"_id": 123456, "abc": {"def": {"ghi": 123}}})
```

Comment: ive been using this just building that using a function, thanks anyway